# how to write C++ DLL file for python correctly?

Tags: python, c++, dll, g++, ctypes

this is my test.cpp file.(*I also used makefile to create dll file*)

```
//#include <iostream>

int foo(int a)
{
    if (a > 1)
        return a + 1;
    else
        return a + 2;
}
```

when I run following code in python

```
import os 
import ctypes

lib_bfs = ctypes.WinDLL("D:\\advanced_programming\\HW7\\cpp_part\\libtest.dll")
print(lib_bfs)
```

everything is ok and I get this output from python.

```
<CDLL 'D:\advanced_programming\HW7\cpp_part\libtest.dll', handle 69d00000 at 0x2b7677e6400>
```

but when I change my test.cpp in this way(I just uncommented iostream):

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a)
{
    if (a > 1)
        return a + 1;
    else
        return a + 2;
}
```

I get the following error from python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/advanced_programming/HW7/cpp_part/connector.py", line 4, in <module>
    lib_bfs = ctypes.WinDLL("D:\\advanced_programming\\HW7\\cpp_part\\libtest.dll")
  File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\advanced_programming\HW7\cpp_part\libtest.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

this is also my dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMjSF.png)

***by the way I have to mention that when I use Linux, everything is just fine.(I just used .so files) but there might be some problem with windows***

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you need to export a class or a sruct, you need to specify the `__declspec(dllexport)` like this `class __declspec(dllexport) Color`. Member functions are not needed to be exported one by one explicitly as by exporting the class automatically exports all the members.

Comment: @dhirajWishal tnx. could u plz give me a good documentation to read about it?

Comment: The official MSVC documentation would be a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-160

Comment: @DhirajWishal I think he doesn't want to export the class (it's probably just an internal class), only the function is exported (with C linkage). It seems the problem arises because using `std::string` introduces a dependency on `libstdc++.dll` (or something) that is not found during loading of his `libbfs.dll`.

Comment: @heapunderrun Oh yeah that might be it. My bad :/

Comment: @heapunderrun tnx. would u plz take a glance at my code ? I just edited it.

Comment: @DhirajWishal i just edited my code is there anything wrong with std::string??

Comment: The reason (probably) why the issue arises is might be with the dependency with `libstd++.dll` as most C++ `std` libraries are defined there. If your using MSVC, the `vcruntime.dll` must be linked.

Comment: How do yu compile/build your *.dll* on *Win*?

Comment: Your code edit completely changed the question.  FYI, `ctypes` only understands C types, not C++, which is why your pre-edit code doesn't like classes or std::string.  Your current edit makes no sense.  `iostream` isn't even used.  Also, unless specifically using __stdcall-declared functions, use `CDLL` not `WinDLL`.

Comment: @DhirajWishal could you please give me a documentation to learn how to  link DLL file ? I just used Makefile to create a single DLL file.tnx

Comment: @CristiFat using g++ on windows and makefile

Comment: @MarkTolonen both ```CDLL``` and ```WinDLL``` doesn't work.

Comment: @ali You could try adding `-static-libgcc` or `-static-libstdc++` when compiling the source file. If it doesn't work, I think its something to do with the call convention (I think it should be `_stdcall`) or the `ctypes` not understanding what's going on (because its made to work with C).

Comment: You have other problems, like the DLL isn't in the right place or a dependency is missing for the "module not found" error, but `CDLL`, for your source, is correct. Perhaps the C++ library is linked in due to including `iostream`, but the library is not being found.

Comment: dear @DhirajWishal  i addedd this line but it didn't resolve the problem ```g++ -std=c++17   -O3  -I./h -g -fPIC -shared ./cpp/test.cpp -o ./libtest.dll -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++```

Comment: @DhirajWishal I added my dependency graph. do u see any problem ?if there is anything wrong with my DLL why C++ can load it correctly and python can't?

Comment: @ali Try placing the `libwindpthread-1.dll` next to your `dll` and try again (which is at `F:/strawberry/c/bin/`). If it doesn't work, try `CDLL` instead.

Comment: @MarkTolonen so why C++ works correctly and can load it but python can not ?

Comment: @DhirajWishal . thanx a lot . what was the problem????

Comment: @ali At this point there are 2 things that comes to my mind, its either because python couldn't locate the `kernel32.dll` and `MSVCRT.dll` files, or its because its searching for a C library but you provide it with a C++ library. For the first, you could locate them and copy paste them next to your `dll`. If it doesn't help, you might have to look into another python module to load your `dll`.

Comment: @DhirajWishal can u give me a roadmap to do deeper my knowledge about shared library ? I actually know what is happing under the hood.

Comment: @ali The MSVC documentation is good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160#:~:text=In%20Windows%2C%20a%20dynamic%2Dlink,stored%20in%20a%20separate%20file.

Comment: @DhirajWishal . you helped me a lot . thanks

Comment: @ali No worries, Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @DhirajWishal
first I added the following line in my makefile.

```
g++ -std=c++17   -O3  -I./h -g -fPIC -shared ./cpp/test.cpp -o ./libtest.dll -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

then I placed  `libwindpthread-1.dll` (which was in  `F:/strawberry/c/bin/` dir ) next to my makefile and the problem was solved.